# Timeline of kubernetes events

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to be able to see all of the various things that happened to a kube cluster on a timeline, including when nodes were found to be dead, when new nodes were added, when pods crashed and when they were restarted.

So far the best that we have found is `kubectl get event` but that seems to have a few limitations:

- it doesn't go back in time that far (I'm not sure how far it goes back. A day?)
- it combines similar events and orders the resulting list by the time of the latest event in each group. This makes it impossible to know what happened during some time range since events in that range may have been combined with later events outside the range.

One idea that I have is to write a pod that will use the API to watch the stream of events and log them to a file. This would let us control retention and it seems that events that occur while we are watching will not be combined, solving the second problem as well.

What are other people doing about this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-) Feel free to take the [tour] to learn more about this community

Comment: This sounds like a great question to ask in the [Kubernetes special interest group for cluster operations](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/kubernetes-sig-cluster-ops).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310287/kubernetes-sort-pods-by-age/73614140 (my answer: `kubectl alpha events` https://stackoverflow.com/a/73614140/67824)

Answer (score 28):

- My understanding is that Kubernetes itself dedups events, documented here:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/design/event_compression.md 
  Once that happens, there is no way to get the individual events back.

  See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/36304 for complaints how that loses info.  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/46034 at least improved the message.  See also https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/pull/1291 KEP for recent discussion and proposal to improve usability in kubectl.
- How long events are retained?  Their "time-to-live" is apparently controlled by kube-apiserver `--event-ttl` option, defaults to 1 hour:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/da53a247633/cmd/kube-apiserver/app/options/options.go#L71-L72

  You can raise this.  Might require more resources for `etcd` — from what I saw in some 2015 github discussions, event TTL used to be 2 days, and events were the main thing stressing `etcd`...

In a pinch, it might be possible to figure out what happened earlier from various log, especially the kubelet logs?

#### Saving events

- Running `kubectl get event -o yaml --watch` into a persistent file sounds like a simple thing to do.  I *think* when you watch events as they arrive, you see them pre-dedup.
- Heapster can send events to some of the supported sinks:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/blob/master/docs/sink-configuration.md
- [Eventrouter](https://github.com/heptiolabs/eventrouter) can send events to various sinks: https://github.com/heptiolabs/eventrouter/tree/master/sinks

Comment: How can I change `event-ttl` for an already launched cluster, or how to specify `event-ttl` before creating a cluster? For example if I would like all my events in a cluster to be available for 24 hours? Is there a command for that? Thanks in advance! (I am running k8s on a GKE)

Comment: No idea, deserves a question => I see you opened https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904245/how-to-change-time-to-live-of-gke-cluster-events-from-default-1h0m0s

Comment: Modify the `--event-ttl` flag: In the manifest file /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml find the `command` or `args` section and add or update the `--event-ttl` flag with the desired value, like `--event-ttl=24h` for 24 hours. (I'd like to show an example, but multi-line code markdown isn't allowed in comments.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the pod specific events tab in the [Dashboard](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ui/)?

Some events from a cluster I have running in GKE:

[image]

Comment: Ah. I should have clarified that I'm using kubernetes on AWS so I'm limited to what I can get from the command line or API.

Comment: Dashboard is a cluster add on. You can run it anywhere. Source is on github. See these install instructions: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ui/#accessing-the-dashboard

Comment: Oh, neat. I hadn't noticed that. Based on your screenshot, though, it seems to have similar problems to `kubectl get events` in that it dedups events. My fear is that it just pulls from `get events` and doesn't go back any further either.

Comment: Dashboard does not do any magic, it uses the API and the events will be the same as from kubectl.

Answer (score 0):

kubernetes/heapster can persist event to gcl and influxdb, but for now there is no api to access stored data