# How to change time-to-live of GKE cluster events (from default 1h0m0s)?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running GKE k8s deployments/jobs that take a long time to execute - from days to weeks (Machine Learning).
Default GKE Events expire after 1h, which is not enough to debug problems that can occur during training, like OOMKilling, etc.

`kube-apiserver` isn't exposed in GKE, so I'd like to find a way to access and change a property like `event-ttl`.

How can I change `event-ttl` for an already launched cluster, or how to specify `event-ttl` at a cluster creation? For example if I would like all my events in a cluster to be available for 24 hours. Is there a `kubectl` command for that (the `kubernetes` svc is accessible)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's currently not possible. As you said, the `kube-apiserver` flags are currently not user-configurable on GKE. There are plans to expose more such knobs to the users but I don’t know when would this be available.

Comment: Thanks, that would be great to get at some point. GKE + K8s + alpha GPUs work surprisingly very well for me, so exposing extra access to a master would definitely come in handy and grant more independency/control.

Comment: Is this still the case? It has been some years.

Comment: @chamini2 highly doubt, especially if it still doesn't show up on GKE docs. GKE allows customizing very few flags. And events are exported to Cloud Logging so there's even less reason to allow users to set this flag.